# PWA Service worker notification click

Tags: javascript, notifications, progressive-web-apps

i'm trying do show a notification and do something when it's clicked.

```
    try {
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration()
        .then(reg => {
            reg.showNotification("Guarda il videoclip!", {
                body: "clicca qua!",
                icon: "images/she_is_fire.png",
                vibrate: [100, 50, 100],
                tag: 'sample',
                actions: [{ action: 'explore', title: 'Guarda', icon: 'images/she_is_fire.png' }],
            });
            self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
                event.notification.close();
                window.open("https://youtu.be/PAvHeRGZ_lA");
            }, false);
        })
        .catch(err => alert('Service Worker registration error: ' + err));

} catch (err) {
    alert('Notification API error: ' + err);
}
```

I added the eventlistener but it never gets fired.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The correct place for handling clicks of Service Worker-based notifications is in Service Worker. You need to move your listener - the part with `self.addEventListener('notificationclick', ...)` - to your Service Worker code.

Note that you don't have `window` access there. To navigate to the URL, you'd need to use [`clients.openWindow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/openWindow) instead.

So your app-side code will only have the `reg.showNotification` call and your handler in the Service Worker will look like this:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
  event.notification.close();
  clients.openWindow("https://youtu.be/PAvHeRGZ_lA");
});
```

Comment: Thanks!!! you saved me :) Where to place it is a thing that is missing on the docs :(

Comment: Two more quick question: now the notification doesn't behave like a native android notification, i see the icon in the top bar but when the notification is toggled (reg.showNotification...) the notification doesn't appear. Another problem that i have is that clients.openWindow(...) referring youtube always opens it in chrome and doesn't launch the app, but an href opens it. Have you faced these kind of problems?

Comment: How can we do this in angular?

Comment: what if i want to open dynamic link on notification click ?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? You can always send a payload in `notification.data` and use it in the handler in any way you need.

Comment: For anyone who may not understand or use sample code from [MDN like this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification), the `notificationclick` event code must be in service worker JS file. In MDN case, it must be in **sw.js** file.

Answer (score 4):

Always remember, after adding code ([refer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48550019/5263842) ) in service-worker.js , restart your browser to reflect the changes. I was making change and not restarting browser window , got me frustrated !

Comment: If you're using Chrome, you can just go to Developer Tools -> Application -> Service Workers -> skipWaiting. No need to restart the whole browser every time.

Answer (score 0):

Just for complementary explanation, here is why is used `self` inside a service worker file according to Google Web Fundamentals:

> The weirdest bit of this code to most developers who are new to
> service workers is the self variable. self is commonly used in Web
> Workers, which a service worker is. self refers to the global scope,
> kind of like window in a web page. But for web workers and service
> workers, self refers to the the worker itself.

[reference](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/handling-messages)

I am posting this explanation because helped me out understanding all these events including click.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to test this locally using a visual studio generated browser window, try opening it in a different browser or deploying it and it will work.

There's some weird glitch with VS and `localhost` that doesn't have this event fire.

I spent 2 hours debugging this. Hopefully this saves you all some time.